# Add custom tab for product edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, backend, tabs

I would like to add custom tab in admin panel for product edit page and display all products in table, just like in tab "Recent products" or "Up-sells".

After that, I want to get selected products and display them on product page.

I'm new to Magento, so if anyone knows how to do this I would be very thankful.

Comment: This tutorial maybe just what you need. https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135344)